# For @SpringBootTest @Import of @TestConfiguration class does nothing, while @ContextConfiguration overrides as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Considering following integration test annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
                properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WorkerTestConfig.class})
//@Import(value = {WorkerTestConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"dev","test"})
public class NumberServiceITest {
```

The role of WorkestTestConfig is to override real bean/set of beans during integration startup, whenever I use `@ContextConfiguration` the real bean is backing off and the one from the WorkerTestConfig is used, whenever I use `@Import` the real bean is still created and fails the test.

The `WorkerTestConfig` itself is as trivial as possible:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class WorkerTestConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ScheduledExecutorService taskExecutor() {
        return DirectExecutorFactory.createSameThreadExecutor();
    }
}
```

can anyone explain please yet another magical behavior of @SpringBootTest annotation? If you reproduce the same behaviour please confirm so I can go to issue tracker, as I've seen people using `@Import` with `@SpringBootTest` here on SO and nothing prohibits it in spring boot docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-excluding-config

Totally puzzled on what's going on.

Version: 2.1.2.RELEASE

**Update:**

Also tried to remove the real bean to see if the issue is with just overriding, but `@Import` annotation is just dead in the water, does not work -> unable even to create a bean, @ContextConfiguration has additive/overriding behavior, import does nothing at all.
Fully qualified import for the annotation is:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

Also tried to change from `@TestConfiguration` to `@Configuration` just for the sake of it, nothing at all. DEAD.

**Update 2:**

The `@Import` works with standard spring test though :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Some.class,
                                 Some2WhichDependsOnWorkerTestConfig.class})

@Import(WorkerTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeOtherTest {
```

Comment: @TestConfiguration classes will be automatically registered if they're nested classes.  Have you tried this?

Comment: @ck1 WorkerConfig is level 5 same as the test, they are in sibling packages. I don't want it to be nested class because it has great potential for reuse across the integration tests. Ah you edited, yeah as I say, I would like to reuse this config.

Comment: I'm retracting my answer.  You're correct: `@Import` doesn't work with top-level `@TestConfiguration` classes, although the documentation indicates that it should.

Comment: I'm assuming that `MyTestsConfiguration` in `@Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class)` in section 46.3.3 refers to a class annotated with `@TestConfiguration`.

Comment: cool, I will reference the SO on Spring issue tracker

Comment: Backreference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16328

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you have described with Spring Boot 2.1.2 (or the current latest, 2.1.3). An `@Import` of a top-level `@TestConfiguration` class results in the beans in the imported class being defined. Can you please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson will do, thanks

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I've attached the project to closed issue in github, as I initially could not reproduce I had to go with full blown structure as I didn't know exactly what I was looking for. In the end this only happens for ScheduledExecutorService, i.e. in the zip I provided you will see that I expect a call on a mock, but when using Import annotation it configures real ScheduledExecutorService instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order that `@Import` classes are processed when they are used on tests isn't defined. The `@Import` feature for tests was primarily added to allow *additional* beans to be registered easily, there was no intention of it being used to *replace* bean definitions.

If you want to dig into the weeds and see exactly what's going on you can open `ConfigurationClassParser` and add a conditional breakpoint in `doProcessConfigurationClass`. Add the following condition code:

```
System.err.println(configClass);
return false;
```

Now if you debug the application you'll get addition output as the configuration classes are processed.

When you use `classes` annotation attribute without the `@Import` you'll see:

```
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'demoImportBugApplication', com.example.demoimportbug.DemoImportBugApplication
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'original', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/first/Original.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'workerConfig', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/first/WorkerConfig.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'someTestSecondConfiguration', com.example.demoimportbug.second.SomeTestSecondConfiguration
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/GenericCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/SimpleCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/NoOpCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class]
```

When you use the `@Import` without the `classes` attribute you'll get:

```
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration', org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/first/SomeFirstUsingSecondConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/second/SomeTestSecondConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'demoImportBugApplication', com.example.demoimportbug.DemoImportBugApplication
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'original', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/first/Original.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'workerConfig', class path resource [com/example/demoimportbug/first/WorkerConfig.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/GenericCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/SimpleCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/NoOpCacheConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.class]
ConfigurationClass: beanName 'null', class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class]
```

The first version loads `WorkerConfig` before `SomeTestSecondConfiguration` whereas the second version loads `SomeTestSecondConfiguration` before `WorkerConfig`.

You'll also notice that the second version has a `ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration` class which is the thing that triggers the additional imports.

If you look at `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper` you can see in the `getOrFindConfigurationClasses` method that ordering is defined and your additional test classes will always be listed after the primary configuration.

tl;dr If you need defined ordering use the `classes` attribute. If you want to add additional beans and you aren't trying to override anything use `@Import`.

You might also want to look at `@MockBean` which provides a more robust way to replace a bean with a mock.

Comment: @phil.webb. thank you for clear explanation and intention of the annotation as well as handy trick to see what is being loaded. The only thing remaining thing which confuses me is while "ScheduledExecutorService" follows the rules you explained and the order. The "OriginalInterface" is consistently overridden with TestConfiguration bean on Import. Could you please verify second method 'checkWhosGreeting' . When I used condition breakpoint I can see that Original is loaded after yet it isn't overriding test one, ScheduledExecutorService bean works consistently inconsistent vs standard bean :)